# DbFunctions for DateTime/TimeSpan addition (datetime / time(7) in SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following properties in my EF6 code-first model:

```
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
```

EF translates this to the SQL Server columns

```
StartTime DATETIME
Duration TIME(7)
```

This works great so far.

Now I want to load all entries which have their `EndDate = StartDate + Duration` *after* a specific DateTime value. First, I tried it like this:

```
db.Entries
    .Where(x => x.StartTime + x.Duration >= begin)
    .ToList();
```

This does not work, EF does not know how to translate the `DateTime + TimeSpan` addition operator.

So I changed it to this:

```
db.Entries
    .Where(x => DbFunctions.AddMilliseconds(x.StartTime, (int)x.Duration.TotalMilliseconds)
                >= begin)
    .ToList();
```

Here, it theoretically knows how to perform the `DateTime + TimeSpan` addition, but it does not know the `TotalMilliseconds` function:

> System.NotSupportedException: Additional information: The specified type member 'TotalMilliseconds' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Any hints?

Comment: Yeah LINQ is trying to build an sql from your Expression. you are trying to get it to understand something that can't be compiled to sql

Comment: I thought `TIME` and `DATETIME` can be added by `DATEADD` in SQL Server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522221/code-example-for-add-datetime-and-timespan-in-ef-query

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving the Duration as a TimeSpane, you can save the milliseconds component as long or int. In this case you will not have to convert it to milliseconds