# Code Example for Add DateTime and TimeSpan in EF query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I am looking for a code example of this question.

[Using DateTime.Add(TimeSpan) with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781587/using-datetime-addtimespan-with-linq)

I need to add an entire TimeSpan to a DateTime.

I already have tried `SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", SqlFunctions.DatePart("s", b.duration)` but this looks like it is only adding the the seconds part of the TimeSpan.

This is the code I have so far

```
var queryClash = from b in db.calEvents
                where (newEvent.startTime <= (SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", SqlFunctions.DatePart("ss", b.duration), b.startTime)))
                && (newEventEndTime >= b.startTime)
                select b;
```

Comment: Rather then using `SqlFunctions.DatePart("ss", b.duration)` can't you use `SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", timespan.TotalSeconds, b.startTime` ; addin in the total seconds from TimeSpan?

Comment: Instead of the accepted answer, use the [rafael](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781587/using-datetime-addtimespan-with-linq/34346061#34346061)'s answer from the same thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I used:

```
DbFunctions.AddMilliseconds(b.startTime, DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(b.duration, TimeSpan.Zero)) >= endtime)
```